# Html helper messes with relative url's on IIS, ok in IISExpress and Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

Ok,

I use MVC with .Net core, I have a html helper that formats a column header a bit.

```
    public static HtmlString SortableColumnName(string controller, string sortFieldOrder, string columnName, string displayName)
    {
        string[] split = sortFieldOrder.Split('_');
        string resultSort;

        string sortField = split[0];
        string sortOrder = split[1];
        if (columnName == sortField)
        {
            if (sortOrder == "asc")
            {
                resultSort = columnName + "_desc";
                return new HtmlString($"<a href='/{controller}/index?sortFieldOrder={resultSort}'>{displayName}</a><span class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down'></span>");
            }
            else
            {
                resultSort = columnName + "_asc";
                return new HtmlString($"<a href='/{controller}/index?sortFieldOrder={resultSort}'>{displayName}</a><span class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up'></span>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resultSort = columnName + "_asc";
            return new HtmlString($"<a href='/{controller}/index?sortFieldOrder={resultSort}'>{displayName}</a>");
        }
    }
```

This has worked well in the past (.net 4.7 on IIS and Azure) but now the code base is .Net Core.
And here is the funny part. I always use "~/" and these links get expanded correct.
So the name of the site is correct in the url.

`<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

is expanded (correct) to

`<script src="/MvcPortal/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

However, if i put a "~" in my HtmlHelper code it will not expand but stay a "~".
Because it is deployed to IIS my url is missing something. (Works on azure and iisExpres)

Url's created with the taghelpers are correct:

`<a href="/MvcPortal/PSqueries/Create">`

But url's created with the HtmlHelper look like this:

`<a href='/PSQueries/index?sortFieldOrder=PSQueryName_desc'>Query Name</a>`

They are missing the virtual directory name....

I tried a lot but cannot figure out how to solve this.
I think I am struggeling with the Tilde/Slash option. (https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2)

Comment: Can you offer an example because the the code snippet you provided above doesn't contain "~/" , so I think it will make difficulty to reproduce your error.

Comment: If I put tilde slash in my code or will remain tilde slash... Resulting in a faulty url.

Comment: You may try to create a new website on iis and retry deploying to it? And could you pls add more details on how you configure your iis website? Any rewrite url policy?

Comment: Create a new website will not help.